# Upgraded to .NET 6, having issues with EF - SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, c#-8.0

I keep getting this error while querying on an entity that has a Nullable foreign key reference.

I have tried enabling and disabling nullable reference types (NRT) on the project but no luck.

It works when `JobId` is not null value and throws an exception when it's NULL.

My entity looks like this:

```
public class Employee 
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid? JobId { get; set; }
  
    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("JobId")]
    public virtual Job JobDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Any inputs here, please?

Error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Guid()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
> at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: [DataMember] is not necessary for an EF entity, it's used for things like XML serlialisers.  I think the error is not from the `JobId`, but from the `Id` as it says the value can't be null, but JobId is nullable.

Comment: @Neil Id is PK in the table and it always has a value

Comment: Can you please share the query which leads to the exception? _"I have tried enabling and disabling nullable reference types (NRT) "_ - since `Guid` is a value type this expectedly would have no effect.

Comment: `Guid? JobId` is nullable. So make `Job JobDetails` also nullable => `Job? JobDetails`.

Comment: For what `virtual`? I guess that you used lazy loading before? Are you using proxies now? If not, remove this modifier.

Comment: Let me clarify, are you still using EF 6 or have you moved to EF Core? I think my comment about lazy loading is not relevant

Comment: @GuruStron My query is simple - ctx.Set<Employee>().Where(p=>p.Id ==id).SingleOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of notes: according to [entityframeworktutorial.net](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx), you're not applying the ForeignKey attribute properly, the [ForeignKey] should be applied to the key property, not the other way around:

```
[DataMember]
[ForeignKey("JobDetails")] // You're telling JobId is the foreign key for JobDetails 
public Guid? JobId { get; set; }

[DataMember]    
public virtual Job JobDetails { get; set; }
```

Then, it's worth mentioning that you need the ForeignKey attribute only if the property name does NOT match the reference property name. So, if your Job entity class has a primary key property named JobId (exact match), you don't need the JobId property on Employee, at all.

Then, on some personal notes, I'm also wondering if you have added an ICollection property to the Job entity, and also if it's necessary to define and if it's necessary to define JobDetails as virtual...